# PHP MySQLi Update failing

Tags: php, mysqli

I am updating an existing database using the following code.

```
  ALTER IGNORE TABLE `payouts` ENGINE = InnoDB;
  ALTER IGNORE TABLE `users_UNIQUE` ENGINE = InnoDB;
  DROP INDEX IF EXISTS `userhash` ON `payouts`;
  DROP INDEX IF EXISTS `address` ON `payouts`;
  DROP INDEX IF EXISTS `ip` ON `payouts`;
  DROP INDEX IF EXISTS `slid` ON `payouts`;
  ALTER TABLE `payouts` ADD KEY `userhash` (`userhash`),ADD KEY `address` (`address`),ADD KEY `ip` (`ip`),ADD KEY `slid` (`slid`);
  DROP INDEX IF EXISTS `userhash` ON `users_UNIQUE`;
  DROP INDEX IF EXISTS `address` ON `users_UNIQUE`;
  ALTER TABLE `users_UNIQUE` ADD KEY `userhash` (`userhash`),ADD KEY `address` (`address`);
  UPDATE `settings_UNIQUE` SET `value` = '58.3' WHERE `settings_UNIQUE`.`name` = 'version';
```

The issue is that the last query which updates to current version doesn't update. 
I am not getting any error messages, it just doesn't update.

If I run this directly in database via SQL it updates but not via PHP.

PHP I am using.

```
$db_update = array(
    '58.3' => array(
        "ALTER IGNORE TABLE `payouts` ENGINE = InnoDB;",
        "ALTER IGNORE TABLE `users_".$faucet_id."` ENGINE = InnoDB;",
        "DROP INDEX IF EXISTS `userhash` ON `payouts`;",
        "DROP INDEX IF EXISTS `address` ON `payouts`;",
        "DROP INDEX IF EXISTS `ip` ON `payouts`;",
        "DROP INDEX IF EXISTS `slid` ON `payouts`;",
        "ALTER TABLE `payouts` ADD KEY `userhash` (`userhash`),ADD KEY `address` (`address`),ADD KEY `ip` (`ip`),ADD KEY `slid` (`slid`);",
        "DROP INDEX IF EXISTS `userhash` ON `users_".$faucet_id."`;",
        "DROP INDEX IF EXISTS `address` ON `users_".$faucet_id."`;",
        "ALTER TABLE `users_".$faucet_id."` ADD KEY `userhash` (`userhash`),ADD KEY `address` (`address`);",
        "UPDATE `settings_".$faucet_id."` SET `value` = '58.3' WHERE `settings_".$faucet_id."`.`name` = 'version';"                 
    )
);


foreach($db_update as $v => $update){
    if ($v <= $installed) continue;
    foreach($update as $query){
        if(!$conn->query($query)){
            echo $conn->error;
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `If I run this directly in database via SQL it updates but not via PHP` Where is the PHP code? And also https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp.

Comment: added PHP code, but think it will cause more confusion that good.

Comment: Updated PHP again, what do you mean by tried dumping?

Comment: It says that it updated one row. Any chance it's a transaction or caching issue?

Comment: @Phil I checked the database itself, the value isnt updated.

Comment: @Phil I posted var dump above. No errors I can see.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I dont know what you mean by a transaction or caching issue. If I run the code and then check the database then it should be updated.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but `if ($v <= $installed) continue;` should be in the outer loop, not the inner loop, since neither variable changes during the inner loop.

Comment: Have you tried just running them one at a time and see if that works? Then tossing them into the array and loop?

Comment: Your original post showed that one row was being updated. So, why is that update not being retained? You might be in a transaction (not shown) that gets rolled back instead of committed? Or, since you didn't say how you knew it wasn't working, it might be that the database is indeed being updated but the version number is being displayed elsewhere by code that's using a cached version somehow.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I removed the image from the question since it was just noise but that _"1 row updated"_ was from where OP executed the queries in PHPMyAdmin. It wasn't from their PHP code

Comment: Ok I am getting a little confused regarding the transaction and cache. It wouldnt make sense all the previous queries would get updated by not the last one even though it say its did.

Comment: I have no idea how I would have disabled auto-commit. The script is installed on multiple host and all are having same issue updating the version.

Comment: @Phil additionally this is v58.3 I have used this line of code to update since v1. In  this update it is an issue. If I run just the update version query it will update, just not with the other queries in the update.

Comment: Start at the beginning... 1) When verifying, are you looking at the same DB **host**, **database** and **table** as your PHP script? Note the difference between `settings_UNIQUE` and `settings_dogefaucet`. 2) What is the current value of `settings_dogefaucet.value` for the "version" entry? 3) Check all your code for any uses of `$conn->autocommit(false)` or `$conn->begin_transaction()`

Comment: @Phil #1. Yes I am looking at same database details, UNIQUE was used in my example above just stating that this changes depending on the install, the same db has multiple settings tables all will different ending. #2. Current version is 58.2 #3. I have not used either $conn->autocommit(false) or $conn->begin_transaction() in my code.

Comment: @Phil any further insights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve I added update after query loop.

```
if($installed && $version > $installed){
    $conn->query("UPDATE `settings_".$faucet_id."` SET `value` = '".$version."' WHERE `settings_".$faucet_id."`.`name` = 'version'");
}
```